# XForms Convert a list of items into strings/array?

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just want to display items from a list in a label Text

**CS code**

```
var query = (from Table in listtable
 join Dimension in listdimension on Table.Id equals Dimension.ExDim
 select new { Table.TableName }).ToList();

string result = string.Join(" ", query);

Listview.Text = result;
```

**xaml code**

```
<Label x:Name="Listview" />
```

After building it displays :
{ TableName = ABC }{ TableName = DCE }{ TableName = PPM }

Where am I wrong?
Seems like convert a list into a array a grid

Result I want :

ABC  DCE PPM

Thanks for help

Comment: No idea why you creating list of anonymous types, but anonymous types are nice that way - there is reasonable `ToString` implemented producing output you see (compared to most other types that just return  type name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = (from Table in listtable
join Dimension in listdimension on Table.Id equals Dimension.ExDim
select Table.TableName).ToList();

string result = string.Join(" ", query);
```

Comment: for the record, this is basic C#/LINQ, nothing specifically to do with Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting a new anonymous object in the query. If you want just the table name, you can change that query to return a list of strings.

```cs
var query = (from Table in listtable
    join Dimension in listdimension on Table.Id equals Dimension.ExDim
    select Table.TableName).ToList();
```

Comment: You're right ! And if I want just an object from the table ?